# PowerShell - How to delete signature

Tags: powershell, ms-word

I have made a powershell script that detects signatures within MSWord files. I would like the script to DELETE those pesky signatures.

Can someone help? I'm having trouble finding a .delete that works here.

```
$folder = "c:\test\*"
$include = "*.doc", "*.docx"
$word = new-object -comobject word.application
$word.visible = $false
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Drawing

Get-ChildItem -path $folder -include $include | ForEach-Object {
    $doc = $word.documents.open($_.fullname)
    $howmany = 0
    for ($i = 1; $i -le $doc.Shapes.Count; $i++) {
        if ($doc.Shapes.Item($i).type -eq [Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoShapeType]::msoPicture) {
            $howmany++
        }
    }
    if ($howmany -ne 0) {
        $_.name + " contient " + $howmany + " signature(s)"
    }
}
$word.quit()
cmd /c pause | out-null
```

Comment: Do you want to remove all shapes? Or only the last one?

Comment: Any and all Shapes that are signatures

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't test ATM if the `$doc.Shapes` enumeration provides a delete method, but you could try this:
**EDIT** changed script after BenH's hint

```
## Q:\Test\2018\04\25\SO50023775.ps1
$folder = "c:\test\*"
$include = "*.doc","*.docx"
$word = new-object -comobject word.application
$word.visible = $false
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Drawing

Get-ChildItem -path $folder -include $include | ForEach-Object {
    "Processing $($_.FullName)"
    $doc = $word.documents.open($_.fullname)
    $howmany = 0
    for ($i = 1; $i -le $doc.Shapes.Count; $i++) {
        if ($doc.Shapes.Item($i).type -eq [Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoShapeType]::msoPicture) {
            $howmany++
            $doc.Shapes.Item($i).Delete
        }
    }
    if ($howmany -ne 0) {
        $_.name + " contient " + $howmany + " signature(s)"
        $doc.save()
        $doc.close()
    }
}
$word.quit()
"press any key..."
cmd /c pause | out-null
```

Comment: Shape collections do appear to have a [delete method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/VBA/Word-VBA/articles/shape-delete-method-word). But it looks like you need to call the delete on the shapes collection passing in the index of the shape object.

Comment: does not work. When it tries to delete, i get this output : void Delete ()

Comment: Could you try the [previous version](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/50024453/revisions) and just use `$Shape.Delete` with parentheses appended `$Shape.Delete()` ?

Comment: That worked! I had to place a $i-- after the delete, but it worked ! Thanks !

Comment: Thanks for the help ! Sorry if I didnt accept the answer right away, im not very familiar with this site. Thanks again guys !